# Uncrustify: How to add a new line before declare or assign variable?

Tags: c, uncrustify

Using the Uncrustify Code beautifier,
How to add new line before declare and assign a variable ?

I want to convert this:

```
void Function()
{
    int a;

    function();
    a = 1;
    int b = a;
    function();
    function();
}
```

To this expected result:

```
void Function()
{

    int a;

    function();

    a = 1;
    int b = a;

    function();
    function();
}
```

Also possible,
I would accept a solution if it adds a new extra line per assign too

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Is this a code formatting question or about printing new lines?

Comment: I changed the text to a question. This is a code formatting question using Uncrustify https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify